# Root test for complex series and cancelling powers with absolute values

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, power-series, absolute-value, absolute-convergence

The root test for convergence of a complex power series is given as

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|a_{n}\right|} = L$$

If $a_n = \frac1{(1+i)^n}$ then I read that when applying the root test I can just remove the powers since they cancel out:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|a_{n}\right|} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac1{(1+i)^n}\right|} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac1{(1+i)}\right|$$

Why is it ok to cancel the root **outside** the absolute function with the power **inside** the absolute function? For any given $n$ the expression might be negative so I feel this shouldn't be possible.

Thank you.

Comment: $(a^{n})^{1/n}=a$ if $a \geq 0$. Take $a=\frac  1 {|1+i|}$.

Comment: Square root etc is defined to be positive, and absolute value is also positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because
$$|z^n|=|z|^n\qquad\forall z\in\mathbb{C},n\in\mathbb{N}$$
which can be proven by considering both sides in exponential form.

Comment: Thanks but I found a counter-example: If $z=-i$ and $n=3$ then $|(-i)^3|=i$ but $|(-i)|^3=i^3=-i$. What am I missing?

Comment: That's not how the modulus function works...$$|(-i)^3|=|-i|^3=1$$$$|x+yi|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Thank you. Considering $|e^{i \theta}| = 1$ and $r$ is always positive, I think I can prove this now: $|z|^n = |r e^{i \theta}|^n = (|r| |e^{i \theta}|)^n = |r|^n |e^{i \theta}|^n = |r|^n = r^n$ and $|z^n| = |r^n e^{i \theta n}| = |r^n| |e^{i \theta n}| = |r^n| = r^n$ so $|z|^n = |z^n|$

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was thinking.